# Aumann's paper the notation 3

Tags: probability, probability-theory, game-theory

I'm reading the Aumann's collected works and I have a notation question from his paper [here](http://www.dklevine.com/archive/refs4389.pdf) on the page 77
namely what is $\alpha$
in his notation $$F_i(\sigma)=\sum_{s}h_i(s)\prod_{j\in N}\alpha_j(s_j).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is a typo and it should be $\sigma$ instead, as $\sigma_j(s_j)$ is the probability of player $j$ playing $s_j$, so that $\prod_{j\in N}\sigma_j(s_j)$ is the probability of player 1 playing $s_1$ and player 2 playing $s_2$ and so on, so that $F_i(\sigma)$ is the expected payoff for player $i$ of the mixed strategy profile $\sigma$. This is consistent with the rest of the paper.